# I need a function in java where it counts odd or even digits in a specific number and i can choose if i want the the odd or the even digits

Tags: java

taking for example
i have two numbers
JEAN : "5143436111"
SAMI : "4501897654"

I need the funtion to give me this:

i have 7 odd digits in JEAN number
i have 5 even digits in SAMI number

I tried this function but i want to choose if i want the odd or even digits bcz in here its showing both but i want my fuction to give me the choice to choose

`

```
static int countEvenOdd(int n)
{
    int even_count = 0;
    int odd_count = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int rem = n % 10;
        if (rem % 2 == 0)
            even_count++;
        else
            odd_count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    System.out.println ( "Even count : " +
                              even_`your text`count);
    System.out.println ( "Odd count : " +
                              odd_count);
    if (even_count % 2 == 0 &&
         odd_count % 2 != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: What is the expected output of the function?

Comment: i have 7 odd digits in JEAN number i have 5 even digits in SAMI number

Comment: Your code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-even-odd-digits-integer/ 
So it would be better next time if you include a reference from where you copy the code
And this code works 100%, what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
static final int EVEN = 0;
static final int ODD = 1;

static int count(int n, int remainder)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int rem = n % 10;
        if (rem % 2 == remainder)
            count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Even Count: " + count(12233, EVEN));
    System.out.println("Odd Count: " + count(12233, ODD));
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but still it didnt work when i tried to run it thats what it showed me:
EVEN cannot be resolved to a variable
ODD cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: It's because the EVEN and ODD weren't static. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that you really only need to compute the number of odd or even digits, since the other count can be inferred using the total number of digits in the input.  You may use:

```java
int countOdd(long n) {
    int count = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        long rem = n % 10;
        if (rem % 2 == 1) ++count;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return count;
}

long num = 5143436111L;
int odd = countOdd(num);
int even = (int) (Math.log10(num) + 1) - odd;
System.out.println(num + ", EVEN => " + even + ", ODD => " + odd);
```

This prints:

```
5143436111, EVEN => 3, ODD => 7
```